# How to use in main.c a structure defined in another .c file?

Tags: c, file, structure

I declared a struct on a header file, let's take this as example:

```
//file.h
#ifndef FILE_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

#endif // FILE_H_INCLUDED
```

Then I defined that struct on another file, that contains prototypes of function that I will use on main.c:

```
//functions.c
#include "file.h"

Point p = {{1},{2}};
```

Now my question is, how can I use that struct on main.c? Would like to do something like:

```
//main.c
#include "file.h"

printf("Point x: %d", p.x);
```

Now, my real struct got 8 fields and it's an array of 40 elements, so it's 40 rows of code, and I would like to not put it in main.c, as I want it as clear as possible. I can't use global vars tho.

Comment: It looks like you're already using a global variable, `p`.

Comment: what should be the definition then?

Comment: If it is in another file and it is not global then it cannot be directly accessed outside that file. So your two requirements seem to be contradictory. You can define a function in `function.c` that returns `p` or pointer to `p` if that is acceptable.

Comment: @kaylum you mean that I should put all the definition of the struct inside a function, for example: Point initializeStruct (Point p)?

Comment: Don't know. Because your stated requirements are unclear. You tell us clearly what the requirement is and only then can we provide an answer.

Comment: The way you have done would make the structure global.WHy dont you declare 'p' inside main.c and pass it to a function that can be used to populate the structure.The function can then be placed in another file (in the global space).

Comment: I have that long struct define (40 lines of code) and I don't want that to appear on main.c; I want the main.c file to have just few lines of code, and 40 lines of defining would not help.

Comment: But by including file.h in main.c then you have included the definition (The 40 lines of code) What you haven't included is the variable p which is defined in another c file.

Comment: @c_mnon my structure has 8 fields and it's an array of 40 elements, every value of fields is different so I can't use a function to set all these values to my array struct. At least, I think so.

Comment: @Massey101 the definition of the struct (where i assign values) is on the functions.c, in file.h theres just the declaration of that struct

Comment: @Simone Just to make sure that we are using the same terminology, "definition" is in the header and "initialise" is in your c file. I assume by definition you mean initialise.

Comment: @Simone If your only requirement is not to have too much code in main.c then, put 'extern Point p' in file.h . Now in function.c use any number of functions to set the diff values in the structure instance p , once done these can be accessed in main.c.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// file.h
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
void setup_point(Point *);

// functions.c
#include "file.h"
void setup_point(Point * p) {
    p->x = 1;
    p->y = 2;
}

// main.c
#include "file.h"
int main() {
    Point p;
    setup_point(&p);
    printf("Point x: %d", p.x);
}
```

This is ideal as the logic for your struct is contained in a separate file and it does not use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function the returns the address of `p`.

```
 //file.h
 Point *Point_p(void);

//functions.c
#include "file.h"
static Point p = {{1},{2}};
Point *Point_p(void) { return &p; }

//main.c
#include "file.h"
printf("Point x: %d", Point_p()->x);
```

Comment: I agree that this is the most straight forward way to answer the question but it isn't ideal as it encourages the use of global variables.

Comment: @Massey101 Where is the global variable?  `p` is static and local only to `functions.c` and no other variables are involved.